# Visual Studio 2017: Is it possible to disable Node.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript, less, visual-studio-2017

Ever since upgrading to Visual Studio 2017, I have about five or six Node.js processes running and constantly taking up tons of CPU. This seems to happen mostly when debugging my ASP.NET website, and especially when compiling my Less and TypeScript files.

Frequently, just hitting Ctrl-S inside a Less file is enough to have Visual Studio stop responding for 20 seconds or more. This is extremely frustrating.

To be clear, this is not a Node.js project. I'm guessing that Visual Studio 2017 uses Node.js behind the scenes, perhaps for its Less and TypeScript compilation.

Is there any way to disable Node.js in Visual Studio 2017 and still have my TypeScript and Less files compile correctly?

Comment: Also asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769106/visual-studio-2017-node-js-server-process-turn-off

Comment: I hear ya man. Even my buddies that work at MSFT can't answer that question (or won't... what are they planning...)

Comment: VS doesn't natively support compiling LESS files.  How did you configure that?  Are you using an extension, or maybe gulp tasks?

Comment: Also, as I commented in the thread posted by @GlenLittle, please file feedback about this through VS.  There's a few different features that launch a Node process, and it'd be nice if we can narrow down which ones are causing this issue.

Comment: Can you also let me know the path to the node.exe process(es) that are spawning?  I was able to repro this and filed a bug but I want to see if it's the same case as what you're running into.

Comment: One last question: how many instances of VS are you running at once?  On my machine, I get 4 node processes from 1 instance of VS (one from the JS language service, 2 from web tools tasks, and 1 is a child process from one of the web tools ones).  We should each (JS/web tools) be reusing our node instances so you shouldn't get more than these AFAIK.

Comment: @Jimmy, I'm super pumped that you were able to repro this and open a bug. Thank you! I'm using gulp to compile the LESS files, specifically the latest edition (3.3.0) of gulp-less.

I have a total of five Node.js processes. One is at:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\common7\ServiceHub\Hosts\ServiceHub.Host.Node.x86.exe.

The other ones are all launched from:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Web\External\node.exe.

Comment: @Jimmy - I've some some info in the linked question.