# How to enable and disable ServiceHub.exe components in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

**How can I disable it?**

In the following screenshot you can see six processes that all begin with **ServiceHub**. These start when I start [Visual Studio 2017 Community](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2017). Annoyingly, they do not stop when I exit Visual Studio 2017 Community. I would like to know how to disable these so that they do not start in the first place.

**How can I enable it?**

What turns these on?

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: I also have these guys running when DevEnv is open, but they exit once all DevEnv processes have gone. I think they are used by some dev env plugins from Microsoft, ServiceHub is some kind of a generic proxy that communicates with Azure or VS Online, I think , I don't think you can get rid of them (w/o endangering your setup)

Comment: @Simon: I wish I knew what caused them to turn on. I do not use Azure or VS Online. I thought maybe I had installed a package that has a dependency on those and maybe I absentmindedly skipped past the notification of the dependency. Or even my vs2017 CE during update caused those to be turned on. I still do not know. But I am certain that nothing in my solution uses these services. For example, I can forcibly terminate them in Task Manager and all of my project unit tests are still passing with green lights.

Comment: Oh, you know, a standard VS install literally hundreds of addons w/o one notices... I'm not even speaking of 3rd parties, Microsoft alone is reponsible for a good part

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Comment: (An answer is related to [a meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420316) - though it *may* have been automatically deleted by the time you read this (then only visible for users with more than 10,000 reputation points).)

Comment: Five years later, and VS2022 still leaves bits of this thing running...

Answer (score 8):

### First Workaround:

> *Tools > Options > Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > Language Service...*
>   Uncheck **Enable the new JavaScript language service**.

**OR:**

> Tools > Extensions and Updates > TypeScript for Microsoft Visual Studio > **Disable**

### Second Workaround:

Rename **ServiceHub.Host.Node.x86.exe** and if you want to enable it just rename to original file:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\ServiceHub\Hosts\ServiceHub.Host.Node.x86\

### Linked:

1. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/30326/how-to-avoid-nodeexe-and-servicehubhostnodex86exe.html
2. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/31406/visual-studio-2017-nodejs-server-process-turn-off.html
3. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/27033/nodejs-server-side-javascript-process-consuming-to.html?childToView=27629#comment-27629
4. [Visual Studio 2017 - Node.JS Server Process - Turn off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769106/visual-studio-2017-node-js-server-process-turn-off)

Comment: When using VS 2017 the second workaround worked at first, but VS now crashing, attaching VS to debug the exception reveals that the exception message is:
`Could not start process: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\ServiceHub\Hosts\ServiceHub.Host.Node.x86\ServiceHub.Host.Node.x86.exe`  I'm not sure why it's an intermittent crash, but it's not a valid workaround because of this.

Comment: follow this post https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/31406/visual-studio-2017-nodejs-server-process-turn-off.html

Comment: The "Second Workaround" is a truly bad idea. It results in a crash the moment you open a solution that has JS/TS in it, and makes Studio unstable.

Comment: This is more or less a rehashing of the Stack Overflow question *"[Can I turn off the Node.js server process associated with Visual Studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769106/)"*. Which indicates that one of the questions is a duplicate of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Those errors happened when I was using *Visual Studio Installer* (after downloading the packages I selected) which was opened through the option to install more project templates (*New Project* window) in Visual Studio.

I just **closed Visual Studio** and the conflicts were gone from the Installer allowing the installation to proceed normally.