# Npm install discord.js error (npm ERR! code 1)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm getting this error while downloading discord.js I tried a few things like npm clean cache etc but it didn't work.

What should I do ?

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\thesc\Desktop\dc bot\tkn\node_modules\ffmpeg-binaries
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install
npm ERR! internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
npm ERR!   throw err;
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\thesc\Desktop\dc bot\tkn\node_modules\lzma-native\binding-v3.0.8-node-v83-win32-x64\lzma_native.node'
npm ERR! Require stack:
npm ERR! - C:\Users\thesc\Desktop\dc bot\tkn\node_modules\lzma-native\index.js
npm ERR! - C:\Users\thesc\Desktop\dc bot\tkn\node_modules\decompress-tarxz\index.js
npm ERR! - C:\Users\thesc\Desktop\dc bot\tkn\node_modules\ffmpeg-binaries\install.js
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
npm ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
npm ERR!     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\thesc\Desktop\dc bot\tkn\node_modules\lzma-native\index.js:13:14
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\thesc\Desktop\dc bot\tkn\node_modules\lzma-native\index.js:597:3)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12) {
npm ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm ERR!   requireStack: [
npm ERR!     'C:\\Users\\thesc\\Desktop\\dc bot\\tkn\\node_modules\\lzma-native\\index.js',
npm ERR!     'C:\\Users\\thesc\\Desktop\\dc bot\\tkn\\node_modules\\decompress-tarxz\\index.js',
npm ERR!     'C:\\Users\\thesc\\Desktop\\dc bot\\tkn\\node_modules\\ffmpeg-binaries\\install.js'
npm ERR!   ]
npm ERR! }

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\thesc\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-19T21_18_55_425Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve npm install error “npm ERR! code 1”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67399785/how-to-solve-npm-install-error-npm-err-code-1)

Comment: How to solve npm install error “npm ERR! code 1” The solutions in the question did not work.

Comment: Looks like a package is missing. Can you post what you are specifically running on the command line and what other packages you have installed already?

Comment: it was fixed when i deleted the package files, thanks for the help.