# npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1

Tags: node.js, laravel

When i try to install npm that's occur

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

> ```
> npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
> ```

Before that i tried to put the url of node js in path of my computer properties / advanced system setting / Environment variables / path

C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;

Answer (score 1):

Ok so let's do something new here and not actually just suggest the same things as everyone else in other threads, something that works.

First: the error message may have **nothing** to do with the actual problem, it may come from something else. So let's ignore that.

I tried this and this works (yes, you can't just copy paste a solution but on the other hand this will work, so you choose):

ISSUE: one of your packages is not longer compatible due to node-version or whatever.

SOLUTION: find the problematic package

1. Open package.json and cut all under dependencies to a text file
2. Now run `npm install` without anything in dependencies
3. If this works, all fine
4. Now add back the dependencies, one by one from the top
5. After each new dependency (don't forget to remove the , comma in the end), run `npm install`.
6. Once you have run this many times enough, you will see at which package it breaks.
7. Now let's google that package and see how it can be updated or if we can live without it.