# Npm install error. 'npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python, stack Error'

Tags: python, node.js, npm, nuxt.js, npm-install

Whenever I try to run `npm install` or `npm update` in my nuxt.js(vue.js) project, error below appears.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/kyeolhan/ForWork/BackOffceFront/node_modules/deasync
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node ./build.js
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.2 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="/path/to/pythonexecutable"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "/path/to/pythonexecutable"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (/Users/kyeolhan/ForWork/BackOffceFront/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:302:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (/Users/kyeolhan/ForWork/BackOffceFront/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:136:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/Users/kyeolhan/ForWork/BackOffceFront/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:179:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (/Users/kyeolhan/ForWork/BackOffceFront/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:266:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (node:child_process:406:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:418:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/Users/kyeolhan/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/node" "/Users/kyeolhan/ForWork/BackOffceFront/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/kyeolhan/ForWork/BackOffceFront/node_modules/deasync
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kyeolhan/.npm/_logs/2022-03-28T12_56_28_864Z-debug-0.log
```

python3 is installed in my mac (Apple M1 Pro, macOS Monterey 12.3).

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.12
```

I also tried with --python option with paths below.

```
$ which -a python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
```

```
npm i --python="/usr/bin/python3"
npm i --python="/opt/homebrew/bin/python3"
```

But it doesn't work

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/kyeolhan/ForWork/BackOffceFront/node_modules/deasync
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node ./build.js
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.2 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking Python explicitly set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "--python=" or "npm config get python" is "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "/usr/bin/python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="/path/to/pythonexecutable"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "/path/to/pythonexecutable"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (/Users/kyeolhan/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:330:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (/Users/kyeolhan/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:159:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/Users/kyeolhan/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:202:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (/Users/kyeolhan/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:294:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (node:child_process:406:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:418:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/Users/kyeolhan/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/node" "/Users/kyeolhan/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/kyeolhan/ForWork/BackOffceFront/node_modules/deasync
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kyeolhan/.npm/_logs/2022-03-28T13_05_45_769Z-debug-0.log
```

I think the 'deasync' package is requiring python since only projects containing that package in package-lock.json make this error.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Why would you need python for a node-based project? Do you have a github link?

Comment: @kissu No… because it’s code of my company. It’s private. But I heard that ‘node-gyp’ has python dependency.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I resolved this issue by downgrading node version (to v14.19.1).

#reference!

[How to solve npm install error “npm ERR! code 1”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67399785/how-to-solve-npm-install-error-npm-err-code-1)

Answer (score 2):

Yes downgrading to nodejs V 14.19.a worked for me as well.
You are probably try to run react app to test services like aws.

if you dont downgrade it remove the node saas dependency as it is not compatible with new version  of node js
but then if your code again give error if they require the package.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33481313)

Answer (score -2):

I resolved by:

```bash
apt install build-essential -y
apt install python3 -y
```