# Using brain.js in nodejs server but getting error gpu.js not present

Tags: javascript, node.js, artificial-intelligence, backend, brain.js

I'm using brain.js library for creating Nural network.
Package installed perfectly, but when I ran the server then I get this error.

Cannot find module gpu.js

Then I installed "npm i gpu.js"
Then I got this error - This below error says that install visual studio 2022 latest version and run this in that. I did but didnt worked.

code part

````
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\priya\JSAIML\ytHelper\node_modules\gl
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.8.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.3 found at "C:\Users\priya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\priya\JSAIML\ytHelper\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\priya\JSAIML\ytHelper\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\priya\JSAIML\ytHelper\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\priya\JSAIML\ytHelper\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\priya\JSAIML\ytHelper\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\priya\JSAIML\ytHelper\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\priya\JSAIML\ytHelper\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:420:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\priya\\.nvm\\versions\\node\\v18.8.0\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\priya\\JSAIML\\ytHelper\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\priya\JSAIML\ytHelper\node_modules\gl
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\priya\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-08T17_34_38_565Z-debug-0.log```

this is how my code looks like 

code ->
````

```
import express from 'express';
import * as brain from 'brain.js/dist/index.js';
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import  ytData  from './md/data.js';


dotenv.config()
const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000


const network = new brain.recurrent.LSTM();

const trainingData = ytData.map((item,i)=>({
    input : item.title,
    output : item.views,
}))


network.train(trainingData,{iterations : 2000});

const outputData = network.run("Simple Machine Learning With JavaScript - Brain.js")


app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    // res.json({message : `On this title you will probably get around ${outputData} views`})
    res.send("hello")
})



app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log(`Running up the hill at ${PORT}km/hr`)
})
```

```
**Any help will be appreciated.**
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced similar pain.

To resolve it, I did the following:

1. First, I [used an older version of node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67487338/906192), to resolve an `“npm ERR! code 1”` error. Not sure if this part is relevant for you, but I needed it:

   - [Installed](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-version-manager-nvm-install-guide/) `nvm`, and then ran:
   - `nvm install v15.14.0`
   - `nvm use v15.14.0`
2. Then, I installed an older version of `brain.js`, to resolve the `Cannot find module 'gpu.js'` error:

   - Updated `package.json` with an older version: `"brain.js": "^1.6.1"`
   - Re-installed: `npm install brain.js`
   - Ran the app again: `node index.js`

OK - hope that's helpful :)