# Can't deploy functions to firebase

Tags: firebase, npm, next.js, google-cloud-functions

after running "firebase deploy --only functions" I get the next error

I have tried to delete de functions folder, and firebase files to try "firebase init" again, run nmp ci, and encounter the same error

Also the location of my up is the server eur3 and here tries to deploy it to  "createUserDocument(us-central1)" us-central1

Please help, dont know what to do

```
 $ firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'reddit-clone-729f9'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> build
> tsc

+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
+  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged C:\Users\carlo\Desktop\proyectos\reddit-clone\functions (65.02 KB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: creating Node.js 16 function createUserDocument(us-central1)...
Build failed: ...file
npm ERR! Missing: is-arrayish@0.2.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ansi-styles@5.2.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: react-is@18.2.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: kleur@3.0.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: sisteransi@1.0.5 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: is-core-module@2.11.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: path-parse@1.0.7 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: supports-preserve-symlinks-flag@1.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: shebang-regex@3.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: buffer-from@1.1.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: char-regex@1.0.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: glob@7.2.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: minimatch@3.1.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: is-number@7.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: picocolors@1.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: convert-source-map@1.9.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: makeerror@1.0.12 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: tmpl@1.0.5 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: isexe@2.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: imurmurhash@0.1.4 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ms@2.1.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: yallist@3.1.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ansi-styles@3.2.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: supports-color@5.5.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: color-convert@1.9.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: color-name@1.1.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: has-flag@3.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ms@2.1.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: minimatch@3.1.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: brace-expansion@1.1.11 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ms@2.1.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: cliui@8.0.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: yargs-parser@21.1.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: minimatch@3.1.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: brace-expansion@1.1.11 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: minimatch@3.1.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: brace-expansion@1.1.11 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: sprintf-js@1.0.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: p-try@2.2.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: brace-expansion@1.1.11 from lock file
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Clean install a project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm ci
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Options:
npm ERR! [-S|--save|--no-save|--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional|--save-peer|--save-bundle]
npm ERR! [-E|--save-exact] [-g|--global] [--global-style] [--legacy-bundling]
npm ERR! [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--no-package-lock] [--foreground-scripts]
npm ERR! [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
npm ERR!
npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-02-25T03_38_57_463Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        createUserDocument(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

Answer (score 0):

After executing [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72256347/9378123) and not having success.

I delete the package-lock.json file and run the deploy again

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75594741/9378123

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Running `npm config set legacy-peer-deps false` worked for me.

Found it in this thread https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/6216