# Cant install NPM ijavascript package, it keeps erroring out (npm ERR! errno -4058)

Tags: node.js, npm, ijavascript

I am very new to node/npm etc. Pardon me, if I am maxing my terms.

I am trying to set up **[ijavascript](https://github.com/n-riesco/ijavascript)** on my system, so that I can take notes of interactive JavaScript code in VSCode (Jupyter Notebook), like I currently can with Python.

I am stuck on actually setting it up, the instructions, [Windows (Official Python Distribution)](https://github.com/n-riesco/ijavascript#windows-official-python-distribution) say:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install jupyter
npm install -g ijavascript
ijsinstall
# Or run: %appdata%\npm\ijsinstall
```

I managed to do `pip3 install --upgrade pip` and `pip3 install jupyter`  but `npm install -g ijavascript` always throws an error:

```
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! path C:\Temp\node_modules\zeromq
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-24T23_30_15_508Z-debug-0.log
C:\Temp                                                                                                                                                                         00:30 Wednesday 25-10-2023 _cnpm install -g ijavascript
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! path C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v21.1.0\node_modules\ijavascript\node_modules\zeromq
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-24T23_30_54_675Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried it without the global option, `npm install ijavascript`, for a moment a folder is created in working directory but then its deleted.
I can install other packages with NPM just fine, both globally and locally. I also tried downgrading to an older version of Node, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67399785/how-to-solve-npm-install-error-npm-err-code-1),  but it did not help.

I am on windows 11

Comment: The error is saying `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` doesn't exist. So does it?

Comment: @Phil it does exist, I just double checked. System environment variable for `system32` directory is also in place.

Comment: Did you try downgrading your `node` version? I had similar errors that specifically mentioned the `zeromq` dependency. I was using `node v21.1.0` just like you. When I downgraded to `node v18.18.2`, the `npm install ijavascript` command worked. I'm on MacOS but the errors and `node` versions are similar enough that it could be an incompatibility between `zeromq` and `node` version. If you fixed it another way, please share your solution.

Comment: @AndreiCalinescu, hey pardon me, as you suggested I added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There were a number of errors that I had to step through and solve one by one:

1. CMD not being found in my path, as suggested to me by Phil
2. Node not being able to build some of part the `ijavapscript` package, I think there is C++ code that needs to be compiled at package install, because Microsoft build tools were not present on my system
3. Python not being found in my path
4. Python `/script/` not being found in my path
5. Either NPM or Node v21.1.0 is making use of Python library **diskutils**, which has been depracted as of `3.12`, see [the distutils package (Python 3.12) #92584](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/92584).

For those on Mac, I am not familiar with Mac, but check that Node/NPM can find the external tools that it needs (Python/Shell/Build Tools). The last point (5) is what gave me the most headache, as when I chose to let Node download and set up things its own way (the last tick on the windows installer), it was using Chocolatey to install Python 12 (which deprecated **diskutils**). When I chose to do this part on my own by

1. Installing  Python 11 (which has diskutils)
2. and sourcing the MS build tools from, here [Microsoft's Node.js Guidelines for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#compiling-native-addon-modules)

Finally, making sure everything is in place at the ENV Path, I was able to get it working on Node  21.10

The links that helped me:
[Microsoft's Node.js Guidelines for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#compiling-native-addon-modules)
[How can I solve error gypgyp ERR!ERR! find VSfind VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879150/how-can-i-solve-error-gypgyp-errerr-find-vsfind-vs-msvs-version-not-set-from-c)
[Node on Widnows](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows)
[Windows-Build-Tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools)