# This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^13.0.0, but Angular version 12.2.13 was found instead

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, angular-cli

My [Ionic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_(mobile_app_framework)) project was running fine a month ago. Today when I tried `ionic serve` or `ionic build`, I get the below error:

[image]

What CLI version is compatible with Angular version 12.2.13? If you really want to know why I am asking this question you can ready further.

So I followed the advice to upgrade to Angular 13 on the official Angular website, I used the following command: `npm @angular/cli@13 update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13`.

This route asked me to upgrade my Node.js to version 16 (latest, current). After upgrading Node.js to v16 I retried to upgrade to Angular 13 and during this process the installation failed/stopped due to unsupported dependencies and so on.

I googled most solutions, tried, and wound up with a project where all my plugins can't be found and so on. So I reversed the above process by uninstalling Node.js v16 to v12, removed npm, the [node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) folder and now I am back at the point where I am getting the below error in the picture.

Here's my developer environment from `ionic info`:

[image]

Here's a copy of my *package.json* file:

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.8",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.8",
    "@babel/compat-data": "^7.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.23.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.23.0",
    "@ionic-native/full-screen-image": "^5.23.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/photo-viewer": "^5.23.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage-angular": "^3.0.6",
    "bufferutil": "^4.0.1",
    "call-number": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "^2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "utf-8-validate": "^5.0.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.2.8",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^5.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^9.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.12",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer.git",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "description": "Vuyou's Funerals",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROIDX_CORE_VERSION": "1.6.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {}
    },
    "platforms": []
  }
```

Comment: Updated angular locally, using ngUpdate

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I don't think I understand what you mean? What I am asking is, what is the correct CLI version for `Angular v12.2.13` ?

Comment: try changing `angular-devkit/build-angular` version from `^13.0.2` to `^12.2.8`

Comment: @AlexElin you saved my entire world! Thank you very much now my app is running again. I wonder how on earth the CLI version changed

Comment: This question is being [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413532/audit-that-doesnt-have-full-error-message-as-text), which explains its sudden scrutiny.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 42):

```
npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.2.13 --force
npm i @angular/cli@12
```

Comment: worked on this bug for almost 1 day, and got a solution here.

Comment: I used `ng update` and everything was updated except `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` so I had to do it manually. Thanks for the answer and saving me time.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same error, but I was using V 11.2.14.

The simple solution is to go to the *package.json* file and change

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.0.2"
```

(it is inside dependencies)

to your compatible version.

So when I changed it to

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.3",
```

it worked.

Answer (score 9):

### if you use @angular-builders/custom-webpack

Whoever is facing this issue, update `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` to its latest version in the *[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)* file.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to **update your angular version across multiple major versions** - if you get the below error while using "ng update" - "Updating multiple major versions of '@angular/cli' at once is not supported. Please migrate each major version individually.
Run 'ng update @angular/cli@12' in your workspace directory to update to latest '12.x' version of '@angular/cli'."

You have to do the following steps to update step by step:

1. run `ng update`
2. you will get a list of items to be updated with the command to update
3. run each command to update along with `--allow-dirty --force`

for and eg: [image]

to update angular cdk here run `ng update @angular/cdk@12 --allow-dirty --force`

4. do the same as above for all the items on the list
5. after completing updating the items with the command given, again run `ng build` and check whether all the errors are gone.
6. if you have more errors regarding the update again run `ng update` and continue with steps 2 to 5 until all the update errors are resolved

Comment: Thanks! I use this solution to update from 12 to 15 (version by version) it works!

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74854090/edit) (it covers answers and program text output as well). (But *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:" or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue with Angular 13.

> This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^14.0.0,

I solved it using

```
npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.0.2 --force
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to upgrade your Angular version then the best solution for this type of errors is just delete your project, again clone the repository, and run `npm install`.

Comment: I had this error where it was saying that this version of CLI is only compatible only with angular 15 but angular 13.0 was found instead. so I did above and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was about updating this package (I upgraded from Angular 13 to 14, but this was left out):

`yarn add @angular-builders/custom-webpack@14 --dev`

Comment: Thanks. This helped me, nothing above.. Just updated some legacy system from Ang13 to 14

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by updating all my ng dependencies to the same version as my cli version.

Run `ng version`

This was how it looked like.

```
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1500.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.0.4
@angular-devkit/core            15.0.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.0.0
@schematics/angular             16.0.0
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      5.0.4
```

Then update the outdated versions.

```
ng update @angular-devkit/build-angular
ng update @angular-devkit/core
```

Run `ng version`. This should look like this.

```
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1600.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.0.0
@angular-devkit/core            16.0.0
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.0.0
@schematics/angular             16.0.0
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      5.0.4
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the *[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)* file, update the below `devDependencies` version to the CLI version which you have of Angular CLI.
2. Suppose you have you have version 10 for below dependencies and your Angular CLI is 16, then update the below dependencies version to 15 or 16

   ```json
   "@angular/cli": "^15.2.9",
   "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.9",
   ```