# Angular build keeps asking for different version of CLI

Tags: angular

Whenever I try to build the angular app I receive this message from terminal: "This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^13.0.0 || ^13.1.0-next, but Angular version 10.2.1 was found instead."

I tried uninstall and install (both locally and globally) specific versions of Angular but to no avail. What am I doing wrong.

This is a copy of my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0-RC1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js",
    "start:local": "ng serve --configuration=development --proxy-config proxy.conf.local.js",
    "start:local-be": "ng serve --configuration=development --proxy-config proxy.conf.local-be.js",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/common": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/localize": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "^10.1.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.7.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.7.0",
    "angular2-toaster": "^8.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "immer": "^7.0.14",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-custom-validators": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^10.0.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.1.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^10.1.6",
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.7.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.4.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of Angular and Angular CLI is your project using?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69946766/6513921

Comment: Yes I am running it with ng serve and I already tried the solutions from other posts.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect your application package.json, most likely your project angular version is 10 whilst CLI is newer.

Update your project to version 13 it with:
`ng update @angular/cli@^13 @angular/core@^13`

Or downgrade your CLI, -g meaning global.
`npm install -g @angular/cli^10 -g`