# Getting the error "Cannot use import statement outside a module" in WebStorm

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to import *wellknown* in to my JavaScript file by doing `import * as *wellknown* from "node/querystring";` but I keep getting this error:

> Cannot use import statement outside a module

I have tried to change *import* to *require*, and I even added type module to my *package.json* file, but nothing helped.

I did my npm install in my console and it says up to date. I even tried to put it in to an `<script>`, but I couldn't figure out the src. I tried something like this:

`<script type="module" src="node_modules/wellknown/wellknown.js"></script>`.

How can I fix it?

This is my *package.json* file:

```
{
 "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "node": "^17.7.2",
    "wellknown": "^0.5.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's my fault, but I entered your package.json and created an app.js with `import * as wellknown from "node/querystring";` did `npm install` and `node app.js` and I get `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/root/app/node_modules/node/querystring' imported from /root/app/app.js`.  So perhaps your instructions to reproduce can be adjusted so that I can easily reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Wyck I think u need to npm install wellknown

Comment: `wellknown` is named in your package.json so `npm install` will install it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access your *wellknown* dependency? If so, the way to do that would be `var wellknown = require('wellknown');`

`import * as wellknown from "node/querystring";` will import every module in *querystring* as *wellknown*. The query string is legacy and won't likely work with new code.

For the script tag, the source has to be either a CDN version of the code needed, or you need to serve or expose your *[node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder)* folder at root domain '/' for this approach to work.

Comment: I'm just trying to use wkt function that is in the wellknown libIary and If do require I get the error message: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at map.js:1:13" and when I go on top of require and hit alt enter I get a suggestion to change it into import

Comment: @hasbullah how are you trying to access this node module ? is it through vanilla js or a framework such as node or react?

Comment: @hasbullah by default require is not a valid command in client side javascript, i suggest you look into https://requirejs.org/ or some alternative.

Comment: its through vanilla js