# Suddenly React cannot execute the 'create-react-app' command. Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Even --force or --legacy-peer-deps didn't work.

Transcript:

```
npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in /home/zahid/my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

added 1353 packages in 2m

171 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

Initialized a git repository.

Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: my-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"<18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@12.1.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!   @testing-library/react@"^12.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /home/zahid/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/zahid/.npm/_logs/2022-04-11T22_25_02_229Z-debug-0.log

npm install --no-audit --save @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.14.1 @testing-library/react@^12.0.0 @testing-library/user-event@^13.2.1 web-vitals@^2.1.0 failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run this first:

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

And try your command again.
It worked with me!

Comment: What does this do? How does it work? OP mentioned "*--legacy-peer-deps didn't worked*", how is this different?

Comment: I ran a wrong code with legacy-peer-deps. That's why didn't worded for me on linux. But above answered code worked for me nicely. Thanks. @Bergi

Answer (score 11):

**This is going to solve the problem:**

1. *npm config set legacy-peer-deps true*

   **Explanation:**

   The --legacy-peer-deps flag was introduced with v7 as a way to bypass peerDependency auto-installation; it tells NPM to ignore peer dependencies and proceed with the installation anyway. This is how things used to be with NPM v4 through v6.
2. *npx create-react-app my-app*

Comment: OP mentioned "*--legacy-peer-deps didn't worked*", how is this different?

Comment: Not sure what error OP has encountered; setting `legacy-peer-deps` do work for me as well. Instead of modifying default npm config, I used environment variable to turn on `legacy-peer-deps` just for this command and it worked. The command I actually use is something like `npm_config_legacy_peer_deps=true npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: This is the *only* answer that explains the magic command line invocations. All the others are "try this" answers.

Comment: This is also the only answer that worked for me too

Answer (score 6):

`npm config set legacy-peer-deps true`

Executing that helped me (on Linux).

Comment: What does this do? How does it work? OP mentioned "*--legacy-peer-deps didn't worked*", how is this different?

Comment: I ran a wrong code with legacy-peer-deps. That's why didn't worded for me on linux. But above answered code worked for me nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

- Run `npx create-react-app` as normal and got the errors
- Go into the *package.json* file and change the React version from 18.0.0 to 17.0.0
- Delete the *[node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder)* folder.
- Then run `npm install`.

No more errors.

Comment: Didn't work for me on Mac

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

I changed this in my package.json (I downgraded the versions):

```
"react": "^18.0.0",
"react-dom": "^18.0.0",
```

To

```
"react": "^17.0.0",
"react-dom": "^17.0.0",
```

Then, remember to remove your folder /nodes_modules and run this in your project main folder:

```
npm i
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command first:

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

and then type the command

```
npx create-react-app app-name
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Delete folder *node_modules* and file *package-lock.json*
2. Go to file *package.json* and change both *react* and *react-dom*'s version to *17.0.0*
3. Now run `npm install`

Things should now work as expected.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., why is it necessary to change the version number? What is it supposed to achieve? What is the idea/gist? Why does it work? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71837844/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).