# Error "sh: node-gyp-build: command not found"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, node-gyp

`npm install` is failing with the below message. I tried deleting the *[node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder)* folder and installing it again, but it didn't work:

> 15104 error command sh -c node-gyp-build
>
> 15105 error sh: node-gyp-build: command not found

How can I solve this?

Error log of `npm install --verbose`:

```
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /Users/johnnycheng/Documents/React Projects/blockchain:fintech/coin-web-test2/node_modules/utf-8-validate
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp-build
npm ERR! sh: node-gyp-build: command not found
npm verb exit 127
npm timing npm Completed in 30755ms
npm verb unfinished npm timer reify 1650620386080
npm verb unfinished npm timer reify:build 1650620407577
npm verb unfinished npm timer build 1650620407582
npm verb unfinished npm timer build:deps 1650620407583
npm verb unfinished npm timer build:run:install 1650620407669
npm verb unfinished npm timer build:run:install:node_modules/bufferutil 1650620407670
npm verb unfinished npm timer build:run:install:node_modules/utf-8-validate 1650620407692
npm verb code 127

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/johnnycheng/.npm/_logs/2022-04-22T09_39_45_773Z-debug-0.log
```

File *package.json* of my project:

```javascript
{
  "name": "coin-web-test2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.6.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "ethers": "^5.6.4",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0",
    "web3": "^1.7.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Check the full error log here: [Full error log](https://github.com/johnnyhoichuen/error-logs/blob/master/2022-04-22T09_44_30_321Z-debug-0.log)

Environment: [macOS v12.3.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Monterey) (Monterey)

[Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) version: 16.14.2

npm version: 8.7.0

Comment: What OS env you are using to do this?

Comment: macOS montery 12.3.1

Answer (score 3):

Try installing using this command as follows:

```
npm install node-gyp
```

Answer (score 3):

Added a global install of node-gyp to my Dockerfile:

```yaml
FROM node:18-alpine
# Installing libvips-dev for sharp Compatibility
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache build-base gcc autoconf automake zlib-dev libpng-dev nasm bash vips-dev yarn
ARG NODE_ENV=development
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

RUN npm install -g node-gyp
```

Enabled me to run docker setup for a Strapi 4.14.4 setup on `node-18:alpine`

Hopefully helpful to anyone else currently Googling this random AF issue.

Answer (score 2):

Running `yarn install` and then `npm install` somehow works.

I don't any idea how.

Comment: Is ur lockfile only in yarn?

Comment: this solution was also helpfull for me yarn install then npm install

Answer (score 2):

I can't find `node-gyp` module in your **package.json** file. 
Try running `npm install node-gyp` and following the instructions for **node-gyp** module [npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp).