# How to use (include) the typewriter npm package?

Tags: npm

I want to use the [typewriter npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typewriter-effect) but I don't understand the example code:

It says... just do npm install, and then do:

```
import Typewriter from 'typewriter-effect/dist/core';

new Typewriter('#typewriter', {
  strings: ['Hello', 'World'],
  autoStart: true,
});
```

I usually use `whatever = require('whatever');` when using stuff loaded via npm.

Why is it different in this case and how can I use it?

As far as I know, npm installed stuff gets into a folder inside node_modules. So, why would I move it into the dist folder?

Thanks!

Comment: you've got this backwards: the `dist` folder is *inside* the `typewriter-effect` folder (which is inside `node_modules`), not the other way around.

Comment: @Esther Thanks for your help. So, I have to explicitly load it from the node_modules folder (node_modules/typewriter-effect/dist/core). But then, why do other packages just do import('whatever') and it already knows where to find it?

Comment: why do you have to explicitly load it from the node_modules folder? I'm pretty sure that happens "automatically", were you having issues?

Comment: @Esther well, that's really weird. It just works. But how does the import statement know it has to look into node modules?

Comment: NodeJS knows to look there for modules, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder

Comment: @Esther Thanks, that's really interesting!