# AppData-Roaming-npm is empty! 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'

Tags: node.js, npm, solidity, hardhat

I am trying to create a new [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/docs) project. Hardhat gives me some pre-created sol files and some scripts. I am just trying to compile this pre-created project, but an error occurred.

```
\\?\C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\SolidityProjects\emptyhardhatfinal\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\solidity-analyzer-win32-x64-msvc\solidity-analyzer.win32-x64-msvc.node    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1210:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\SolidityProjects\emptyhardhatfinal\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\solidity-analyzer\index.js:69:29)    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

1. `npm init -y`
2. `npm i --dev hardhat`
3. `npx hardhat` and create a JavaScript project
4. `npm i --dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox`
5. `npx hardhat compile``` the error above occurred.

My Node.js version is v16.17.0.

User variables for my.user = `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm`

System variables = `C:\Program Files\nodejs\`

I realized that the "AppData\Roaming\npm" folder is empty. But inside another PC that this project worked well is not empty; there is a "[node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder)" folder.

What is the problem and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the [node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) folder and see if the project uses NPM or [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) and run the `npm i` or Yarn according to it.

Comment: '[node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder)' is a folder, not a file. Do you mean a specific file somewhere inside it?

Comment: you have to delete the whole folder