# DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: the `strictQuery` option will be switched back to `false` by default in Mongoose 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, deprecation-warning

I am just making a database called Fruits from my `app.js` and connecting the database to MongoDB using Mongoose.

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    rating: Number,
    review: String
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit({
    name: "Apple",
    rating: 7,
    review: "Taste Good"
});

fruit.save();
```

Whenever I try `node app.js`, I am getting **DeprecationWarning**. Even though I tried using `mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);`, the same error continues as follows:

```
(node:15848) [MONGOOSE] DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: the `strictQuery` option w
ill be switched back to `false` by default in Mongoose 7. Use `mongoose.set('str
ictQuery', false);` if you want to prepare for this change. Or use `mongoose.set
('strictQuery', true);` to suppress this warning.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
D:\Web Development\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-
native\collection.js:158
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

MongooseError: Operation `fruits.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (D:\Web Development\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoo
se\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:158:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)

Node.js v18.12.1
```

And then the second error also continues **fruits.insertOne()**.

Because of this, my MongoDB database is not getting updated.

```
test> show dbs
admin    40.00 KiB
config  108.00 KiB
local    40.00 KiB
shopDB   72.00 KiB
```

I just want to fix this error. But I don't know where to fix this error. For the second part of the error, it seems like it is coming from the *node_modules* itself. How can I fix this error?

Comment: please understand the actual problem before going to the solution, 
1. put  your code in try catch and check what is the error, 
in my case I defined the constraints and I was adding the data that's why it provided the errors
so I just changed my constraint and it worked
moral of the Comment :: if we strictly put the data what might the violation of any constraints

Comment: const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    rating: Number,
    review: String
});
please Change it to 

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    rating:{type: Number} ,
    review: {type: String} 
});
it won't give any error

Comment: Re *"nodule_modules"*: Don't you mean *[node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder)?* (the folder named "`node_modules`")

Comment: Allegedly, it is [from a Udemy course](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74747476/deprecationwarning-mongoose-the-strictquery-option-will-be-switched-back-to/74783773#74783773).

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
```

OR

```
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, () => {
  console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
});
```

```js
const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
        await mongoose.connect(db, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        });
        console.log('MongoDB Connected...');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        // make the process fail
        process.exit(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 35):

I want to give a little more context to existing answers.

When the `strict` option is set to **true**, Mongoose will ensure that only the fields that are specified in your schema will be saved in the database, and all other fields will not be saved (if some other fields are sent).

Right now, this option is enabled by default, but it will be changed in Mongoose v7 to **false** by default. That means that all the fields will be saved in the database, even if some of them are not specified in the schema model.

---

So, if you want to have strict schemas and store in the database only what is specified in you model, starting with Mongoose v7, you will have to set `strict` option to **true** manually.

```js
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
mongoose.connect(Config.mongo_db_connection_string);
```

If you don't want this, you don't have to specify anything, since it will be set to **false** by default. So, you can just connect to the database and that's it.

```js
mongoose.connect(Config.mongo_db_connection_string);
```

Comment: strict Schema is different than the strictQuery option.  As outlined in the mongoose documentation here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict . The Schema strict option is enabled by default and can be changed on the Schema level, also the default behavior is not changing in version 7 of mongoose.  The strictQuery option which can be set globally as you have outlined will be set be set to false in mongoose 7.  https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strictQuery: The strictQuery option is just for query filters.

Answer (score 5):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  rating: Number,
  review: String
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit({
    name: "Apple",
    rating: 7,
    review: "Taste Good"
});

fruit.save();
```

Comment: we should use the given line first then mongoose. Connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});
mongoose. Set('strictQuery', false);

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 4):

This warning message is indicating that the Mongoose library is currently using the "strictQuery" option and that this option will be switched back to "false" in Mongoose 7 by default. Mongoose uses this option to determine whether to enforce strict query syntax. When set to "false", Mongoose will allow query conditions to match multiple properties.

To resolve this warning, you can either set "strictQuery" to "false" in your code by using the following line:

```
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
```

Or, if you want to continue using strict query syntax, you can suppress this warning by setting "strictQuery" to "true":

```
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
```

It's recommended to update your code in accordance with this change before Mongoose 7 is released.

Example:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove this warning with just one line

```
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
```

Comment: Working for me 
You can also try this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74768921/18961814

Answer (score 3):

`mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);`

`mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);`

The above will gives you a warning even if you include that `strictQuery` line.
The solution is nothing but place that `strictQuery` line before `mongoose.connect`:

`mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);`

`mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);`

Then it works!

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution for the first error

You can refer to the command line instruction itself. Just use the suggested line before using Mongoose.

Simply replace:

```js
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

To:

```js
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

Answer (score 2):

The deprecation warning doesn't have anything to do with the error you're receiving. Try removing the whole `mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);` line, and you'll get the same result.

Try replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`:

```js
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/fruitsDB')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Hafez brother. Now it works perfect fine. Finally I can get to access my MongoDB.

**Version:**

MongoDB : 6.0.3
Mongoose : 6.8.0

Comment: Did not worked for me still getting the same warning

Comment: Thanks, it works for mongoose 6.9.1.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Stack Overflow is not a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828). Please don't use Stack Overflow as such. Stack Overflow is not a forum. For example, questions asking for more information belong in comments to the question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb", { useNewUrlParser: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

I am learning the same course on Udemy. [Hafez's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74747476/deprecationwarning-mongoose-the-strictquery-option-will-be-switched-back-to/74750066#74750066) worked for me.

Simply replace

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB', {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

with

```
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/fruitsDB');
```

Comment: What is the title of the course?

Answer (score 0):

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://0.0.0.0/fruitsDB')
```

I think we're doing the same course. I just ignore the Mongoose deprecation warning.

Comment: What is the title of the course?

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to change "localhost" from

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB');
```

to

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fruitsDB");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to put this line of code above all.

```
mongoose.set( "strictQuery", false );
mongoose.connect( "mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/NewDB", () => {
    console.log(`Connected to MongoDB`)
});
```

[See Console Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABc9p.png)

Answer (score 0):

Place the `strictQuery` line before the *connect* line to avoid this issue:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);

mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB",
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Just make sure you import (`require`) and use `dotenv` before the MongoDB connection statement. It worked for me.

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({path: 'config.env'})

// MongoDB connection
connectDB();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem.

Here we go,
[you can find solution in this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTprz.png)

1. simply you need to add this code in **"import section"**
2. > **mongoose.set('strictQuery',true);**
3. const app=express();
4. const mongoose =  require('mongoose');
5. const express= require('express');
6. **mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);**

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75395611/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Mongoose setup //
const PORT = 8000;

mongoose
  .connect(
    process.env.MONGO_URL,
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    },
    **mongoose.set('strictQuery', false)**
  )
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server port: ${PORT}`));
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(`${err} did not connect`));
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74937014/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today). Alternatively, where was it copied from? Was it generated by ChatGPT?

Answer (score -1):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fruitsDB");

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    rating: Number,
    review: String
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit({
    name: "Apple",
    rating: 7,
    review: "Pretty solid!"
})

fruit.save();
```

Comment: Do this your problem will get solved.

Answer (score -1):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const DB = process.env.MONGO_URL;


const connectedDB = async () => {
  try {
    mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(DB);
    console.log(`mongoDB connection : ${conn.connection.host}`.cyan.underline);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`No connection : ${err}`.red.underline);
  }
};

module.exports = connectedDB;
```

Answer (score -1):

**Proper Way**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);
mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://0.0.0.0:0/test", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected!");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("oh no error");
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

const CONNECTION_URL = 
"mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.y3v2mwo.mongodb.net/? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL)
.then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`)))
.catch(error => console.log(error.message));
```

Comment: Please add explanations.

Answer (score -1):

Simply do the below when your connection is established.

```
mongoose.set('strictQuery',false);
```

Comment: Where should it be it? What line?

Answer (score -1):

```js
mongoose.set( "strictQuery", false );
mongoose.connect( "mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/NewDB", () => {
    console.log(`Connected to MongoDB`)
});
```

This solves the Deprecation warning for me after several tries, thanks to the poster...

Comment: Why the backticks around *Connected to MongoDB*?