# Cannot find module 'E:\husky\lib\bin.js'

Tags: windows, git, npm, jhipster, husky

I am using windows to bootstrap a Springboot backend using jhipster. I am running into the error below concerning Husky for git hooks.

```
> eims-back@0.0.0 prepare
> husky install

The system cannot find the path specified.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1042
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'E:\husky\lib\bin.js'
   at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
   at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
   at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
   at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
 requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.13.0
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\Software & Tutorials\Project source\EIMS_BE
```

How to I solve this?

I have searched online for that error but it seems new.

Comment: Try using Node 16.x as JHipster has currently some issues with latest 18.x

Comment: Great...Lemmi try that asap!

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is similar to [nodejs issue 3709](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/3709), which includes some possible solution.

If, as commented, this is a NodeJS version, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75222305/6309), follow the [downgrade process](https://linuxhint.com/downgrade-node-version-windows/).
JHipster is supposed to [support node >=16.0.0](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-lite/blob/b8c6629632ba236c6a08f9597047cdb817f40c55/package.json#L90) but maybe 18.x is too advanced.

Comment: Thanks...let me downgrade....will update