# installing npm before a git pull

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a git repository from github.com and I am using visual studio code. Whenever I try and run the code though its not running I am using npm run dev. Do I need to install the node modules first or perform a pull request from git in order to run npm commands ? I know that replit is running vite so I was wondering if I need to do npm create vite@latest but I don't need a new repository I am just trying to work locally from my computer instead of using replit.

npm create vite@latest.
git clone "my repository" npm run dev

Comment: How to build source code and dependencies are way outside of the scope of git as a tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all you need to understand what node module is and why you have to install it every time you try to clone your project from Git (**and yes you need to install node_modules before running the project**). Read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) to understand what is **node_modules**. The short answer is that **node_modules**  contains packages that are running your project and other additional packages that you install for any purpose, all information about packages that your **node_modules** contains is in **package.json** . You can read more about the **package.json** [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#main).
There is no point in pushing node modules to your git as it's very large file and you already have information about your packages in ***package.json***